# Possible to turn on Airplane mode with WiFi on only?

Tags: applications, settings, calls, airplane-mode

I know the definition of Airplane mode is all communications and radio signals are blocked. But is it possible to turn off the "calling/receiving" part of the phone so your phone is not connecting to a cell tower and only allow Wifi? I've looked into a couple of apps in Google Play but they're either not working or out of date with newer versions of Android.

I know there is strong opinions on both sides of the issue but I'm worried about radiation from my phone since i use it a lot in bed and I hold the phone close to my head and face. At night I'm not worried about receiving calls, so I just want to turn off the phone part and  use WiFi. Is there a way? Or am i just crazy and paranoid?

Comment: It's possible on all Samsung devices, maybe not only on Samsung, but I am speaking about what I have personal experience. Just turn on Airplane mode and turn on WiFi. Simple as a pie!

Answer (score 29):

> Possible to turn on Airplane mode with WiFi on only?

Well yeah, possible in all of my devices running Android 4.2.1, 4.4.2, 5.0.2 and 5.1.1. **This applies for portable hotspot too.**

The radios that are supposed to be turned off when Airplane mode gets enabled are saved  in the key `airplane_mode_radios` under the table `global` inside `/data/data/com.android.settings/databases/settings.db` (**Settings Storage** app's database).

Set up [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC, enable USB debugging in device, connect it into PC, launch a shell, and enter:

```
adb shell settings get global airplane_mode_radios
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/global  --projection name:value --where "name='airplane_mode_radios'"
```

Given the command executed, you would see (either one of the result) something like:

```
cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax
Row: 0 name=airplane_mode_toggleable_radios, value=bluetooth,wifi,nfc
```

You can choose to remove `wifi` from the value to achieve the final objective.

Enter any one of the commands:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_radios  "cell,bluetooth,nfc,wimax"
adb shell content update --uri content://settings/global --bind value:s:'cell,bluetooth,nfc,wimax' --where "name='airplane_mode_radios'"
```

**Note:** Do not copy-paste. Note the string that you got in the first output. Then remove `wifi,` from it and then pass the resultant between the double quotes `""` the way I've shown above.

Now you can turn on the Wi-Fi followed by the Airplane mode. Your Wi-Fi wouldn't turn off.

The need for using ADB was meant for once only.  If you decide to stop Wi-Fi when Airplane mode becomes active then simply include  `wifi` in that key's value.

All good here!

---

### Do you know?

The reason you're able to toggle Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and NFC manually even when Airplane mode is active is because they are mentioned in the value for key `airplane_mode_toggleable_radios`.

Enter any one of the commands:

```
adb shell settings get global airplane_mode_toggleable_radios
adb shell content query --uri content://settings/global  --projection name:value --where "name='airplane_mode_toggleable_radios'"
```

You would see (either one of them) something like:

```
bluetooth,wifi,nfc
Row: 0 name=airplane_mode_toggleable_radios, value=bluetooth,nfc
```

Remove a radio from that key's value such as `wifi` and you wouldn't be able to toggle that radio (Wi-Fi here) again when Airplane mode is active, no matter what, unless of course you revert the changes in that key's value.

Comment: To others having trouble with exceptions when querying with where clauses that have text, you have to escape the single quotation marks. So in the example in the answer, you'd say `--where "name=\'airplane_mode_toggleable_radios\'"` (notice the `\'`).

Comment: This still works perfectly on android 9.0 when backslashes are used.

Comment: If you come across this for forcing Wifi Calling to use Wifi and not randomly switch to a spotty cellular signal, it works on Motorolla G Power 2021 (Android 11) but you need to turn Airplane Mode on *before* starting your call, otherwise it will drop the call.

Answer (score 8):

I use my mobile like this when I travel. So first turn on Airplane mode and then activate WIFI (for example in notification panel). At the end you will have Airplane mode, WIFI activated, and all other connection deactivated.

Comment: Lolwut! This totally works :-D.  Works for Bluetooth also

Comment: Easy way to enable only the radios you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably already correctly guessed, that's device dependent. On my old *HTC Wildfire* (aka *Buzz*) I was able to switch of GSM radio separately – on my *Motorola Milestone 2* (aka *Droid 2*) I am not. What always seems to work is a work-around: Switching to airplane mode, and just enabling WiFi again (and Bluetooth, if you need it).

To not end up "playing piano" each time, this can be automated: [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) e.g. offers to create widgets (rather "shortcuts") for its tasks. So you could first create a task (airplane on, WiFi on, Bluetooth on...), and then make a widget for that. Same for the other direction, if needed. That way you can switch around with the simple tap of a shortcut.

Comment: That works great on all of my devices, using *Tasker* (it's scheduled as my "do-not-disturb night-mode" from 1am to 7am, so wheather info comes in for my morning alarm, but calls don't ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. In your Dialer / Phone app, enter `*#*#4636#*#*`
2. Select `Phone Information`
3. Select `Turn off radio`

Or use an app like [Cell Radio ShutOff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.radioshutoff).

Note also that you can turn Wi-Fi back on during Airplane Mode (though it can definitely be annoying to have it turned off in the first place).