# setting kind of semi - airplane mode

Tags: wi-fi, airplane-mode

In airplane mode, both SIM(s) and wi-fi are disconnected. Is there a way to just disconnect the SIM(s) and keep wi-fi connected without root privilege?

Comment: See my answer: [Possible to turn on Airplane mode with WiFi on only?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/122677)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your Dialer / Phone app, enter `*#*#4646#*#*`
2. Select `Phone Information`
3. Select `Turn off radio`

Or use an app like [Cell Radio ShutOff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.radioshutoff).

Note also that you can turn Wi-Fi back on during Airplane Mode (though it can definitely be annoying to have it turned off in the first place).