# How to make changes done through `adb settings put` persist through device reboots?

Tags: adb

The specific changes I attempted were to a database entry following instructions in this question: [Possible to turn on Airplane mode with WiFi on only?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59664/possible-to-turn-on-airplane-mode-with-wifi-on-only)

The changes to either row would take effect immediately but are reset following a reboot. The updated rows retain their row-id but revert to the previous/default data following reboot.

the exact command I used was:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_radios  "cell,bluetooth,nfc,wimax"
```

The following command would result in an exception where it is unable to find the key:

```
adb shell content update --uri content://settings/global --bind value:s:'cell,bluetooth,nfc,wimax' --where "name='airplane_mode_radios'"
```

I'm using Android 4.2.2 and the latest ADB available as of end of March.

Comment: Does "settings put" *not* persist? I've been using it to modify my captive portal and navigation bar settings, and those do persist as far as I see.

Comment: Also, it's suggested that you open a full `adb shell` and execute the command within, instead of doing everything in a single line.

Comment: Confirm Yan's words: mine are persisted too. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I confirm that on my phone they are **not persisted**, on a LG G6 with Android 8.0.0. Opening `adb shell` didn't help.

Comment: Having the same problem. My settings set by adb put don't persist after reboot, which is annoying.

Comment: I can confirm the same as @MarcoLackovic on a Pixel 3XL with Android 9.  Seriously it is (pardon my language) pissing me off that I have to plug my phone in to run adb commands after every reboot - and even if I don't reboot it STILL forgets it after a week or two.  Seriously makes me wish I was a hermit dying in a cave sometimes that software engineers don't care anymore to quality like they did in the 1970s... (that's an Alan Kay reference on how a 1970s era computer could have instant response but 2GHz PCs take minutes to load)