# Enable vibration and location services while on battery saver

Tags: 9.0-pie, vibration, location-services, battery-saver

I like using battery saver on my Android phone as it greatly extends the battery.  However, there is one app that I use that I would like to exempt from two of the things that batter saver disables - vibration and location services.

I'm ok with the battery usage for these on this one app only but want to restrict all other apps from using the battery.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vibration and GPS are considered as system services, not apps. Thus, it cannot be exempted on the usual setting when Battery Saver is enabled. However, ***since Android 8.0 Oreo*, it is possible to tweak some settings for Battery Saver.**

This is related to the [`BATTERY_SAVER_CONSTANTS`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java;l=11939;bpv=0;bpt=1) global settings that can be modified through ADB.

```
/**
         * Battery Saver specific settings
         * This is encoded as a key=value list, separated by commas. Ex:
         *
         * "vibration_disabled=true,adjust_brightness_factor=0.5"
         *
         * The following keys are supported:
         *
         * <pre>
         * advertise_is_enabled              (boolean)
         * datasaver_disabled                (boolean)
         * enable_night_mode                 (boolean)
         * launch_boost_disabled             (boolean)
         * vibration_disabled                (boolean)
         * animation_disabled                (boolean)
         * soundtrigger_disabled             (boolean)
         * fullbackup_deferred               (boolean)
         * keyvaluebackup_deferred           (boolean)
         * firewall_disabled                 (boolean)
         * gps_mode                          (int)
         * adjust_brightness_disabled        (boolean)
         * adjust_brightness_factor          (float)
         * force_all_apps_standby            (boolean)
         * force_background_check            (boolean)
         * optional_sensors_disabled         (boolean)
         * aod_disabled                      (boolean)
         * quick_doze_enabled                (boolean)
         * </pre>
         * @hide
         * @see com.android.server.power.batterysaver.BatterySaverPolicy
         */
        @UnsupportedAppUsage
        @TestApi
        public static final String BATTERY_SAVER_CONSTANTS = "battery_saver_constants";
```

For the possible integer values of [`gps_mode`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java;bpv=0;bpt=1;l=711):

```
/**
     * Either the location providers shouldn't be affected by battery saver,
     * or battery saver is off.
     */
    public static final int LOCATION_MODE_NO_CHANGE = 0;

    /**
     * In this mode, the GPS based location provider should be disabled when battery saver is on and
     * the device is non-interactive.
     */
    public static final int LOCATION_MODE_GPS_DISABLED_WHEN_SCREEN_OFF = 1;

    /**
     * All location providers should be disabled when battery saver is on and
     * the device is non-interactive.
     */
    public static final int LOCATION_MODE_ALL_DISABLED_WHEN_SCREEN_OFF = 2;

    /**
     * In this mode, all the location providers will be kept available, but location fixes
     * should only be provided to foreground apps.
     */
    public static final int LOCATION_MODE_FOREGROUND_ONLY = 3;

    /**
     * In this mode, location will not be turned off, but LocationManager will throttle all
     * requests to providers when the device is non-interactive.
     */
    public static final int LOCATION_MODE_THROTTLE_REQUESTS_WHEN_SCREEN_OFF = 4;
```

As stated on XDA Developers, [How to Customize Battery Saver Mode in Android 8.0 Oreo](https://www.xda-developers.com/customize-battery-saver-mode-android-8-0/):

1. Install [ADB](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) and [USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb) if necessary.
2. Connect the Android device to the PC with USB and wait until the device is detected
3. Open a command prompt and type `adb devices` to make sure the ADB detects it.
4. Type `adb shell`
5. Decide which values wanted to be changed. Inputting multiple keys are supported with comma separation. For this specific question: `vibration_disabled=false,gps_mode=0`
6. Type `settings put global battery_saver_constants <new_value>`. Note that the change is permanent, so to undo, the user needs to manually input the opposite values instead.

On rooted devices, it is also possible to run the `settings` command directly from the device using terminal apps like Termux.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!  I think for my use, gps_mode=3 would work well, as my app runs a service which is foregrounded for GPS events only when I tell it to run, while other apps that run in the background will get denied and not use extra battery.

Comment: I have tested this out and it works perfectly.  I appreciate this this awesome answer and am going to wait to accept until I can give you some bounty points for it. :-)

Comment: After running with this for over a day, I noticed that my app had stopped producing screen off vibration when in battery saver mode.  I then checked GPS and it would no longer lock or report positions in the same.  But I reconnected USB and reran the adb command and now it's working again.  Perhaps it's less permanent than you thought?  I didn't install anything such as updates in the interim.

Comment: @Michael Unfortunately, I don't have an Android 8.0 or higher to test... and in theory, the setting should preserve permanently. However, I can't expect much since each vendor may behave differently and something might overwrite the value. Perhaps a new question regarding "preserving `settings` value" or "identifying the app/process that modifies the `settings` value" could be a good candidate... (though, the comment thread on [How to make changes done through `adb settings put` persist through device reboots?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/173951) might hint a more complex issue...

Comment: I don't even remember rebooting the device!  Ah well, it's useful although if I'm going to have to periodically reset it I'm going to try to automate it somewhat. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Pixel 3XL and using the system level battery saving,

From: https://dontkillmyapp.com/google

**Pie and pre-Pie**

If you see background processing issues, overall it is a good idea to make your app not battery optimized to ensure it gets the freedom it needs to perform in the background.

For that:

- Go to Settings > Apps > Your app > Advanced > Battery > Battery optimization
- Change view to All apps
- Search for your app
- Choose Not optimized

**From the comments:**

> my app is already not optimized, but vibration doesn't work nor does GPS with the screen off when power saver is on.

So as stated in: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6187458?hl=en

**What happens when Power Saver is on:**

- Apps only refresh their content, like email or news, when you look at the app.
- Location services stop when your screen is off.
- Apps stop doing things in the background, unless you turn off battery optimization.
- Your phone stops listening for "Ok Google.” Instead, you need to squeeze your phone or tap the Assistant icon Assistant.
- Dark theme turns on.
- Your phone and notifications may be delayed.

So your app not receiving GPS/location services is covered by **Power Saver** behavior, as to why vibration isn't working I can't say without knowing why vibration is occurring unless its related to any of the above items like location or a background process.

Comment: my app is already not optimized, but vibration doesn't work nor does GPS with the screen off when power saver is on.

Comment: @Michael See update to answer.